# Can't change text in js , class text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

why can't i change the text of the class in js ? Thanks.

```
function main() {
    "use strict";
    /*global $, jQuery, alert*/

    $('.billion').on('click', function () {
        $('billion').text('Project Viewed');
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: You are missin a dot before 'billion' in `$('billion').text('Project Viewed');`

Comment: You should consider accepting others' answers if they solved your problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
(function($){
    $('.billion').click(function(){
       $(this).text('Project Viewed');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

//Edit
If you have more than 1 "billion", use each:

```
(function($){
    $('.billion').each(function(){
       $(this).click(function(){
           $(this).text('Project Viewed');
       });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.billion').on('click', function () {
       $('.billion').text('Project Viewed');
    });
 });
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.billion').on('click', function () {
       $(this).text('Project Viewed');
    });
 });
```